# Incorporating Blazor custom elements into an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am interested in using custom elements as a means of strangling a legacy ASP.NET MVC website so that I can gradually port it to Blazor.  However apart from the official documents, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#blazor-custom-elements) I can't find any decent documentation.  So it may be that I have misunderstood this technology.  What I would like to do is create a Blazor WASM component called `HelloWorldComponent`, like so:

```
<p>Hello, world!</p>
```

And register this custom element in `Program.cs` like so:

```
builder.RootComponents.RegisterCustomElement<HelloWorldComponent>("hello-world");
```

And then in a separate ASP.NET MVC project use this component in a view, like so:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<hello-world />
```

Is this possible?  And if so how do I reference the Blazor custom element within the ASP.NET MVC app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some steps:

1. You have to publish the blazor wasm stand-alone project to generate the bin folder.
2. Copy the bin/xx/net7.0 subfolders to the old app on the root of your content folder (_framework, _content, etc)
3. On your old app you have to add some lines to the html layout to load the blazor component (also resources if needed (css/js/etc)):

   ```
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements/BlazorCustomElements.js"></script>
   ```

Must been added before the html body end

---

There is another option to use Blazor without using web component as I explain in the following link

https://medium.com/@santiagoc_33226/using-blazor-wasm-with-net-framework-mvc-or-another-old-external-site-7fc0884fcfca

Answer (score 0):

> I am interested in using custom elements as a means of strangling a
> legacy ASP.NET MVC website so that I can gradually port it to Blazor.

Well, you are certainly misunderstanding the compatibility version between blazor web assembly and asp.net MVC app.

Currently,Blazor WebAssembly Integration supports ASP.NET Core in .NET 5 or later. Thus, your legacy application will encounter compatibility issue.

[image]

**Note:** For more details you can have a look our [official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-3.1&pivots=webassembly)

In addition, for [asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [blazor server and web assembly app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) integration you could check these [official document that might be resourceful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-7.0).